# how to run a pooled OLS regression on Python?

Tags: python, regression

Here I have a formula:

,, =  + ,, + ,− + − +  +  + ,,,

I gathered all the data from the Bloomberg terminal, observations in total 1627 rows as syndicated loans with 7 columns as "loan spread at close, log loan spread, loan maturity (months), loan amount, loan secured, profitability, leverage, total assets".

How to code in order to get a pooled OLS regression as the picture below?

[image]

Comment: Don't just ask for code. If you need some code for your problem simply hire someone. If, however, you did code yourself something and have a specific problem, then people here on SO will help.

Comment: Thanks Megajin, it's my first time using Python, indeed, I didn't ask a good question. I will try to code on my own and see how far I go.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Using the `linearmodels` package, you can do this:

```
from linearmodels import PooledOLS
mod = PooledOLS(y, x)
res = mod.fit(cov_type='clustered', cluster_entity=True)
```

Where `y` is the dependent variable and `x` is the independent variable. The PooledOLS accpets a 3th argument `weights (array-like, optional)` to use weights in estimation.

Please refer to this link for more information:
https://bashtage.github.io/linearmodels/panel/models.html#linearmodels.panel.model.PooledOLS

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24636790)

Comment: @PavelKarateev Thank you! I edited my original post.